# Whatever happened to Google Android samples linked in their tutorials?

Tags: android

I seem not to be able to find any of the Google Android samples. For example, I'm reading this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#keyframes, and there is a link to a [MultiPropertyAnimation](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/MultiPropertyAnimation.html) sample which should show how to use keyframes. When I click there, it get redirected to a samples main page, and the sample I'm looking for is not there, or at least I can't find it. The same for quit a few other samples. I also tried importing the samples in Android Studio, which provides a search/filtering interface, and can't find anything there.

Has Google moved the samples, and forgotten to update the rest of the docs? Did the 'old' samples get deprecated and moved elsewhere? Can they still be accessed?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/devbytes/animation/MultiPropertyAnimations/src. Essentially what I did was a  google search for `site:github.com MultiPropertyAnimations`

Comment: Thank you. The question still remain, though - why does Google do it to us, why do they again keep the docs not in sync with the rest?

Answer (score 1):

The latest (and most convenient way) to do it is:

1. open android studio
2. if a project is currently opened, close it (file -> close project)
3. on the following screen choose "Import an Android code sample".

[image]

Also see http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html